# Постинг javascript кода на форуме ввиде ссылки

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли запостить сам javascript в виде ссылки на форум? Дабы при нажатии на которую он выполнялся.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="javascript:func();">link</a>
<a href="http://link" onclick="func();">link</a>
```

На Хешкоде, по-моему, не прокатит.

Answer (score 0):

На форумах все знаки переводятся в их HTML коды на сколько знаю... поэтому и будут выглядеть как &lt и &gt и тому подобное... это будет отображаться как текст а не ссылка.

**UPD**

Когда серверу приходит запрост, то все символы вроде скобок уже переведены браузером в код.

Comment: Большинство безграмотных разрабтчиков пытаются просто зарубить такие символы (вконтакте, например). В результате получается фигня на выходе. Но некоторые, действительно пытаются экранировать символы, так что XSS выполнить не получится.

Comment: В контакте их не рубят... их просто переводят в формат `%FC` и чтото вроде этого

Comment: Не знаю что там они делают, но обычно вылезают какие-то левые символы.. какие-то знаки вопроса и буквы, которых вообще в оригинале не было. А иногда обрезают кусок текста.